# Mass recoloring of PNGs from command line

Tags: macos, images, colors, png, imagemagick

Similar to the mass rescaling command this site taught me [here](https://superuser.com/questions/227151/mass-rescaling-of-pngs), is there a command-line trick for mass recoloring?

To make it specific, suppose I have a bunch of images with RGB and alpha values:

```
apple_original.png  
pear_original.png  
banana_original.png
```

and so on.  I want to have a command-line command to give me the following:

```
apple_orange.png  
pear_orange.png  
banana_orange.png
```

where in each case, the R, G, and B values for each pixel have been multiplied by 1, 0.5, and 0, respectively, and the alpha has been left alone.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Ignacio for the great hint. Based on it, here are the answers:

First of all, to convert a single file. Say we want to convert test.png to orangeTest.png, multiplying R, G, and B by 1.0, 0.5, and 0.0, respectively. Here is the command:

```
convert test.png xc:'rgb(255,127,0)' -fx 'u*v.p{0,0}' orangeTest.png
```

Now, for the mass conversion:

```
for i in *.png; 
   do convert "$i" xc:'rgb(255,127,0)' -fx 'u*v.p{0,0}' "${i%.*}_orange.png"; 
done
```

Answer (score 4):

["Mathematical Linear Histogram Adjustments"](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#linear)